# Download Vimeo blocked video

Tags: download, vimeo, restrict, blocked

Maybe I will get downvoted for this, but I need to know.
I want to download an educational video from VIMEO for personal use, but it says "download blocked by VIMEO". Is there any workaround, or this is definitive protected video I couldn't download?

Thank and have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here what i've learned - there is a workaround and the Vimeo itself offers the solution. Just use the Screen Recording feature of Vimeo to record the video and then download it from your own profile.
Two drawbacks:

1. it is a time consuming endeavour, cause the video must be recorded in real time;
2. the max output quality is 720
   Anyway for the educational videos I wanted to watch offline this is perfectly fine.